# I need to stored PipelinedRDD into a hadoop file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark, rdd

I performed all of these in PySpark.

first I read a file from HDFS into an RDD:

```
distFile=sc.textFile("hdfs.......tsv")
```

then I split them by columns:

```
newfile = distFile.map(lambda line: line.split('\t'))
```

then I extract columns I need:

```
A = newfile.map(lambda r: [r[25], r[79], r[108], r[451]]).collect()
```

So now A is a pipelinedRDD with numerous rows and four columns. I need to store A on HDFS. how do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

`A` is not `RDD` but a local list. If you want to keep `RDD` don't use `collect`. To save the file you can use for example `saveAsTextFile` method:

```
newfile.map(
    lambda r: [r[25], r[79], r[108], r[451]]
).saveAsTextFile(some_hdfs_path)
```

Comment: so you mean if I just do this: A = newfile.map(lambda r: [r[25], r[79], r[108], r[451]]). A is an RDD. However, if I do this: A = newfile.map(lambda r: [r[25], r[79], r[108], r[451]]).collect()   ,    A is a list?

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I mean.